Can we use expressions such as GE or LE in FILTER statement in ABAP 7.5
I've my code written as below
DATA LT_OP TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF TY_ABC
                 WITH EMPTY KEY
                 WITH NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY AB
                 COMPONENTS AB BC CD.

lt_OP =  FILTER #( LT_HIU USING KEY AB
                           WHERE AB = CONV #( to_upper( 'AB' ) ) AND
                                 BC = CONV #( to_upper( 'BC' ) ) AND
                                 CD = CONV #( to_upper( 'CD' ) ) ).

I wanted to a date field where I can use GE lv_date
I've tried using the expression and didnt work

"it didn't work" isn't a very good description of an error. It would be more helpful if you showed us what you tried and what error message or unexpected behavior you got.

It's usually recommended to use >=, <= instead of GE, LE, to be consistent with all modern programming languages.

Yes, you can do that. Not only are the moern comparison operators like >= or <= supported in filter conditions, but the archaic ones like GE or LE as well:
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF struct_data,
    value TYPE string,
    date  TYPE d,
  END OF struct_data,
  
  table_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF struct_data
     WITH DEFAULT KEY
     WITH NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY key_date COMPONENTS date.


DATA(gt_data) = VALUE table_data(
   ( value = 'Asfd' date = '20240101' )
   ( value = 'XYT' date = '20240301' )
   ( value = 'SADFfd' date = '20240501' )
).

DATA(gt_filtered) = FILTER table_data(
     gt_data USING KEY key_date
        WHERE date >= CONV d('20240301')
).

This results is gt_filtered having two of the three rows of gt_data.
I am not sure what your mistake could have been. Maybe you forgot to add the date field to the secondary table key you are filtering by?

DATA(gt_filtered) = FILTER table_data(
gt_data USING KEY key_date
WHERE date >= CONV d('20240301') and date <= CONV D(20240301)
). - this seems to be not working

@user25665577 As I already told you in a comment to your answer: "this seems to be not working" is not a statement anyone can do anything with. You are a professional software developer, aren't you? When you would receive a ticket from a user that just says "Your program doesn't seems to be working", would that be enough for you to diagnose and fix the problem? No. So please explain how it is not working. Does it do something else than you would expect? Is there an error message?

Its working my bad, Thanks so much for your help,

@user25665577  When this answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark icon next to it.
